# Difference between colloid thrusters and electro spray thrusters

Tags: propulsion, ion-thruster

What is the difference between colloid thrusters and ion electro spray thrusters

Answer (score 2):

They appear to be two names for the same thing. See http://lmts.epfl.ch/MEMS-ion-source, for example.

Comment: Link seems to be broken, a good example of why link-only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Wikipedia article [Colloid thruster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colloid_thruster) they are the same thing:

> A colloid thruster (or "electrospray thruster") is a type of low thrust electric propulsion rocket engine that uses electrostatic acceleration of charged liquid droplets for propulsion. In a colloid thruster, charged liquid droplets are produced by an electrospray process and then accelerated by a static electric field. The liquid used for this application tends to be a low-volatility ionic liquid.

The Wikipedia article includes a link to some MIT lecture notes for Aeronautics and Astronautics; On the [Lecture notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-522-space-propulsion-spring-2015/lecture-notes/) page for [16-522-space-propulsion-spring-2015](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-522-space-propulsion-spring-2015/) one can find [MIT16_522S15_Lecture22-23.pdf](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-522-space-propulsion-spring-2015/lecture-notes/MIT16_522S15_Lecture22-23.pdf), the title of which is:

> Session  : Cone-jet Electrosprays, or Colloid Thrusters

These two terms indeed seem to be use interchangeably.