# Can I "tack" towards a laser beam from which I am powering my 100% efficient & massless ion engine?

Tags: physics, mathematics, design-alternative, energy, electric-propulsion

As far as I know, for light and particles taking special relativity into account:

\begin{align}
E^2 &= (T + m_0c^2)^2\\
    &= p^2 c^2 + m_0^2 c^4 &\text{ (particles)}\\[1.5em]
E &= p c & \text{ (photons)}\\[1.5em]
F &= \frac{d\,p}{dt\phantom\,} \ne ma.^†
\end{align}

If I have a bottle of hydrogen or xenon and 100% efficient and massless ion engine and light to electricity converters, I can accelerate away from a laser beam both by absorbing their momentum and by using their energy to accelerate ions back towards the source of the laser.

*I think* but am not sure that it is difficult to impossible to accelerate *directly into* the beam because 1) [this comment](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/48173/how-should-mass-specific-impulse-calculated-for-relativistic-exhaust#comment155580_48173) and 2) a given amount of energy imparts more momentum to a photon than to a particle with nonzero rest mass $m_0$.

**Questions:**

1. Is that right? Even with 100% efficient and massless light to energy converters and ion engines, I can never accelerate directly into a beam of light?
2. If so, for a given particle energy $T$ and rest mass $m_0$ what is the highest angle at which I can accelerate in the half-space (hemisphere) towards the laser beam, if any? Or can I only accelerate into the half-space away from it?

<sup>†</sup>[ref](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/39509)

Comment: no prob! Sadly, I find the moderation here quite objectable, so to avoid me wasting emotional energy in the future, I'll delete my account on this site; it's been an honor :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks for you candor. I find the moderation here to be excellent, even exemplary *Stack Exchange* moderation, and fully adapted to the site's dedication to being welcoming to new users balanced with keeping things cordial and focused on the exploration of *aspects of* space exploration as well as on space itself.

Comment: @MarcusMüller If you feel the site could be improved why not express something in meta? When humans are involved there's always room for improvement,

Comment: the moderator in question just changed the wording of a question, thus clearly invalidating my answer, then without as much as a warning deleted my answer. Then I asked in a comment to the question whether, if he was as unsure about the change as he expressed to be, it was a careful moderation choice to just delete my answer instead of just downvoting it. And he just kept deleting my comments. So, nope, sorry, not wasting any effort on that one – he's the elected moderator, not gonna change him, so leaving this community :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller okay, there might have been some additional considerations that would come to light in a meta interaction. Moderators work in a different and larger information space and broader responsibility space than the rest of us. Anyway, if you have any thoughts on [Have deep-space spacecraft always used some form of spread-spectrum for data downlink?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25780) before you go it would be great to hear them, I'm still confused on the definition of what modulations do or don't count as "spread spectrum". It might be more of an issue of terminology...

Comment: I'm honestly confused, this is a different thing altogether?

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes it is orthogonal in terms of topic. I just ran across your profile yesterday for the first time and thought "Oh great! a radio person!" which is why I made [this long list](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/48193/?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment155672_48193). The next day you're talking about leaving and I'm thinking "Oh no, all those potential answers disappearing..." The spread-spectrum thing has been puzzling me for a long time and I was hoping you might be able to shed some light on that. I see SE's goal as simply to generate good answers, and this question needs one!

Comment: @MarcusMüller but also I'm hoping that is a metaphor for SE in general and this site as well; nothing is perfect here because it's completely open to the internet and a planet full of heterogeneous people; when things feel *even more imperfect than usual* one can always just move on to the next unanswered question, or in my case, to writing one :-)

Comment: @MarcusMüller oh I just ran across the page you are talking about. Ya that sudden deletion does seem uncharacteristic for the site. I definitely don't think that that's worth leaving the site over, and do think it's worth exploring in meta. If you like I can write a meta question about it. But if "you got angry and violated the terms of engagement (code of conduct)" will be the answer, then that's exactly how SE now works in order to accommodate being open to the entire internet. We do need to remain cordial at all times, sometimes even against our will. :-)

Comment: not angry, just not willing to invest effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are making use of fuel (reaction mass), this can only work for a finite time, but it must be possible for a while.  We could imagine that we have a "largish" ship so the energy we get from the source imparts a negligible momentum.  Then we could use that energy to push off from the bulk of the ship to accelerate toward the energy source.  Done.

But it should work well for more realistic setups as well.  As an example, I assume the ship is "large" enough that the xenon exhaust is a minor fraction of the total mass.

I receive 1MJ of photons.  How hard does it "push" the ship?

$$dp = \frac{E}{c} = 0.0033 \text{kg m/s}$$

An engine can generate a relative velocity with xenon of 20 km/s.  Most of the energy will go to the exhaust. How much Xenon can be accelerated from that energy with 100% efficiency?

$$m = \frac{2E}{v^2} = 0.005\text{kg}$$
$$dp = 0.005\text{kg}\ 20\text{km/s} = 100\text{kg m/s}$$

Since this is bigger, we can go in any direction.

The numbers aren't exact even with perfect efficiency (100% of the energy won't go to the exhaust, the engine isn't impulsive so some losses with $dp$, etc.) but the difference easily covers those caveats.

Comment: *This is beautiful!* The incoming photon momentum is absolutely trivial in comparison to what its energy can be used to impart to reaction mass. This result seems to be independent of individual particle mass; protons, xenons or marbles would do if practicalities didn't matter. However if maximum acceleration voltage did matter there would be some preference.

Comment: e.g. [For a DAWN-like solar-electric deep space mission, would using propellant particles much heavier than xenon atoms be beneficial?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43453) vs [Have light gases like hydrogen or helium been explored for ion propulsion?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/43389) and my [battered answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/43412) therein.