# Got Milk? Why is the term "colloid" used in "Colloid or Electrospray thruster"?

Tags: history, engines, physics, chemistry

From [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/25843/12102) to the question "Difference between colloid thrusters and electro spray thrusters" I've extracted the following:

According to the Wikipedia article [Colloid thruster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colloid_thruster) they are the same thing:

> A colloid thruster (or "electrospray thruster") is a type of low thrust electric propulsion rocket engine that uses electrostatic acceleration of charged liquid droplets for propulsion. In a colloid thruster, charged liquid droplets are produced by an electrospray process and then accelerated by a static electric field. The liquid used for this application tends to be a low-volatility ionic liquid.

The Wikipedia article includes a link to some MIT lecture notes for Aeronautics and Astronautics; On the [Lecture notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-522-space-propulsion-spring-2015/lecture-notes/) page for [16-522-space-propulsion-spring-2015](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-522-space-propulsion-spring-2015/) one can find [MIT16_522S15_Lecture22-23.pdf](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-522-space-propulsion-spring-2015/lecture-notes/MIT16_522S15_Lecture22-23.pdf), the title of which is:

> Session  : Cone-jet Electrosprays, or Colloid Thrusters

These two terms indeed seem to be use interchangeably.

---

But neither of those links explain why the liquid must or may be a colloid.

When I (and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colloid)) think of "colloid" we think of the most commonly used example of which is milk. Wikipedia goes on to list mayonnaise, hand cream, and latex as examples of a liquid-liquid colloid. A dilute solution of milk will demonstrate [opalescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opalescence) due to the scattering of light from the colloidal suspension of fat particles. You see this by the blue/red color shift depending on angle from white light, or the strong scattering of a laser pointer's light shining in from the side. [Opal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opal) itself is a [colloid crystal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colloidal_crystal).

**Question:** But do electrospray thrusters really use colloids? And are there colloidal suspensions that are stable in space? Or do they just use ionic or metallic liquids and the use of the term "colloid" is just historical?

---

**below:** [Got milk?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Got_Milk%3F) Colloid example; [Glass of milk on tablecloth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Glass_of_milk_on_tablecloth.jpg). Click for full size.

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that the term colloid comes from the use of such a thruster in atmosphere, where it would produce exhaust in the form of a colloid aerosol in air. In space it would be more of a nullosol.

Comment: @RussellBorogove Oh, I see what you mean. In an atmospheric application the resulting aerosol ("spray") might be the important product, rather than the thrust.

Comment: Oh, I don't know if the exhaust would be *important*, but it would be colloid.

Comment: @RussellBorogove well we don't call LOX/RP-1 engines "Soot Engines" nor LOX/LH2 "Steam Engines", so I don't think we would call a space engine that makes colloidal particles "Colloid Engines" unless the colloid had some significance beyond "that's what's in the exhaust."

Comment: I've got some bad news for you about how things get named.

Comment: @RussellBorogove in the pit of my stomach I have a feeling you might be right. But at least I got to use my "Steam Engines" quip in the process.

Comment: I like the steam engines idea.  I've called them water vapor generators.

Comment: Good question! I've looked at multiple papers on the subject, and the ones discussing "colloid thrusters" *immediately* start talking about *ionic liquids* as the propellants, and ionic liquids are not colloids. Russell Borogove might be right about the rather inappropriate naming history.

Comment: @TomSpilker thanks! The earliest publications or reports may have the best clues.

Comment: @uhoh By the way, I didn't have to click on the image of the glass of milk to get a full-size image: I have a "laboratory example" of one on my kitchen table! ;-)

Comment: I suspect that the fact that the droplets are all like-charged means that they don't agglomerate in vacuum.

Comment: @ikrase I don't know where or how the electrons are offloaded but to remain charge-neutral the spacecraft has to get rid of them somehow, but probably it's with some electron gun off to one side. But I'm not sure of your point about agglomeration; does it matter some how in terms of the use of the term colloid or is it just a general comment?

Answer (score 4):

If [this source](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.489.2947&rep=rep1&type=pdf) is right, they're using the term "colloid" to refer to charged microparticles:

> At sufficiently high voltages, the micro-jet becomes unstable very near the apex, and breaks up into charged droplets (hence the name “colloid”)....

which does not conform to the formal [definition of a colloid](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/colloid):

> A homogeneous, noncrystalline substance consisting of large molecules or ultramicroscopic particles of one substance *dispersed through a second substance*. Colloids include gels, sols, and emulsions; the particles do not settle and cannot be separated out by ordinary filtering or centrifuging like those in a suspension. (emphasis mine)

but I guess they liked the term.

Comment: Yes, but the Dictionary specifies that it's dispersed within a second substance, like a liquid. A vacuum, even a partial vacuum like the LEO environment, doesn't have enough charge density to qualify. I would have preferred that they invent a new term for a new phenomenon, rather than hijack a pre-existing, and in my view inappropriate, term.

Comment: I had multiple undergraduate chemistry courses, and the first reference I found online agreed with what I'd been taught in those chemistry courses, so I stopped there. It didn't seem there was any controversy.

Comment: No red herring intended. It's just that from the text preceding it, "...the one quoted passage..." it appeared to be pointed in the other direction.

Comment: Comment cleanup!

Comment: The four word, parenthetical sentence fragment isn't really a sufficient explanation of why the term has been used by so many scientists and engineers at places like MIT, NASA... They seem to be convinced that the use of this term is important.