# Do colloid thrusters generate thrust by using only droplets or pure ions as well? If they only use droplets, how are they the same as electrospray?

Tags: propulsion, electric-propulsion

In all of the research literature I have read so far, I've seen colloid thrusters explained as devices that gain thrust by releasing only charged droplets from ionic liquids as the exhaust mass. Electrospray phenomenon can also generate individual ions. If colloid and electrospray thrusters are the same (as written in many places on the internet and elsewhere), how do some electrospray thrusters also release ions as exhaust mass? How are these thrusters actually classified? Under which circumstances are only droplets/only ions used and under which circumstances both droplets and ions? For example, if you were to model a plume from an electrospray thruster's emitter, would you consider both droplets and ions or only ions/only droplets in the plume? And how is FEEP thruster different from these two types?
I am so confused.

Comment: Related but not the same: [Got Milk? Why is the term “colloid” used in “Colloid or Electrospray thruster”?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/25845/12102)